# mysql join by using select have where with master column

Tags: mysql, function, join, select, left-join

```sql
select t.* from 
    (
    SELECT p.*
    ,b.id as brand
    ,b.name as brandname
    ,j.id as closed
    ,c.name as customername
    ,l.name as productline
    ,u.user_name as username
    ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,j1.start_date,j2.delivery_date) as total_hour
    
    FROM `project` AS p
    left join customer as c on c.id = p.customer
    left join brand as b on b.id = c.brand 
    left join customer_product_line as l on l.id = p.product_line
    left join users as u on u.id = p.created_by
    left join (select project_id,`status`,id from job where `status` <> '1' group by project_id,`status`) as j on j.project_id = p.id
    left join (select project_id,start_date  from job where project_id = id order by start_date asc limit 1) as j1 on j1.project_id = p.id
    left join (select project_id,delivery_date  from job  where project_id = id  order by delivery_date DESC limit 1) as j2 on j2.project_id = p.id
    
    ) t
```

I have error in `p.id` in last 2 left join

any way to do this by function or proc or other ways

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Is the problem with `where project_id = id`? That's not needed, that's done by `ON j1.project_id = p.id`.

Comment: If you're trying to get the last row for each project, you need to use one of the techniques in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1 in the subquery.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that you get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a correlated subquery in a `JOIN`.

Instead of using `ORDER BY <column> DESC LIMIT 1` in the subquery, just use `MAX(<column>)` in its `SELECT` list. And you can use a single query to get `MAX(start_date)` and `MAX(delivery_date)`.

```
SELECT p.*
    ,b.id as brand
    ,b.name as brandname
    ,j.id as closed
    ,c.name as customername
    ,l.name as productline
    ,u.user_name as username
    ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,j1.max_start,j1.max_delivery) as total_hour
FROM `project` AS p
left join customer as c on c.id = p.customer
left join brand as b on b.id = c.brand 
left join customer_product_line as l on l.id = p.product_line
left join users as u on u.id = p.created_by
left join (select project_id,`status`,id from job where `status` <> '1' group by project_id,`status`) as j on j.project_id = p.id
left join (
    select project_id,MAX(start_date) AS max_start, MAX(delivery_date) AS max_delivery
    from job
    GROUP BY project_id
) as j1 on j1.project_id = p.id
```

Comment: very thanks ............